# Where to look for newest images from Chang'e 3?

Tags: lunar-landing, photography, china, chang-e, solar-eclipse

The tomorrow lunar eclipse is bound to look spectacular from the Moon - and as far as I know, Chang'e 3 is still fully operational, including its 3 high-definition stereo cameras. That means a chance for some awesome photos of what will be a full solar eclipse, with Sun eclipsed by Earth, as seen from the Moon pretty soon - except then I'd need to find them, and I don't know even a bit of Chinese.

Where does the China Space Agency publish photos from Chang'e 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://moon.bao.ac.cn/index_en.jsp) is a source in English, it can be tricky with the translation but essentially you can create a log in and go through a ton of pictures and data :)

The original source (in Chinese): http://moon.bao.ac.cn/

Comment: It has an English version. I edited the link to the English one.